# Issue with Makefile, Makefile:1: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?). Stop

Tags: c, makefile, module, kernel, gnu-make

I'm trying to write a simple Makefile for a module, I've got all the right components, I've replaced all the spaces in the beginning of lines with tabs.

```
Makefile:1: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.
```

This is my Makefile

```
obj-m += hello-1.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: Is that really the Makefile? It looks like your command line.

Comment: That is one weird Makefile.

Comment: sorry copy and pasted the wrong text

Comment: Did you check the other Makefiles it is calling? Errors don't lie, especially this error.

Comment: Your editor is probably configured to convert tabs to spaces. This is sensible under most circumstances, but makefiles don't like this.

Check your editor options for a way to disable that behavior (in case you didn't know, a tab isn't just a key on your keyboard - there is an actual tab _character_, which needs to be at that point instead of space characters).

Comment: If you are on a Unix or Linux system, you can use `cat -t Makefile` to make the tabs explicitly visible.  Each tab will be printed as `^I`.  That way you can make sure you've got tabs where you think you do, or not.

Comment: in order to eliminate the syntax in the Makefile by running the command from shell:           "make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules"

Comment: When it doesn't work and you don't know why, try something simpler. In this case, try a `HelloWorld` Makefile, one with a single rule with a single command: `echo hello`.